# What is the point of a stackoverflow community wiki?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are “Community Wiki” posts on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow)

Today I wanted to start a discussion on Stackoverflow.com, so I carefully made sure the question was flagged as a community wiki. However with in 5 minutes the question was closed. During this time the question was also getting upvoted.

My question is: Is there any way to open a discussion on Stackoverflow if you are NOT famous, Jon Skeet, Jeff Attwood, etc?

Or do you have to be famous so that your questions don't get closed as argumentative or subjective, finally what then is the REAL purpose of community wiki questions. Because they are clearly NOT there for discussion or free thought?

Comment: So you posted a question about the site not on the site for the sites but the programming site in the trilogy of sites?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-wiki+faq

Comment: Here's the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932920/

Answer (score 4):

Nobody can "open a discussion" when the question is both pointless and offensive to everybody who creates useful and good software but doesn't actually invent new languages.

Answer (score 4):

Go to the top of the page, clink the "faq" link. Read the highlighted bit that says:

> Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion.

Please.